# Mots familiers pour désigner tel ou tel objet mathématique

Tags: mathématiques, registre-familier

Je voudrais apprendre quelques mots argotiques pour désigner un objet mathématique quelconque. On trouve beaucoup de mots mathématiques sur la toile, mais il y a encore d'autres mots familiers que l’on utilise.

Au Pays-Bas, j’entends parfois qu’on appelle un ensemble une « bête » ou « gars », parfois par faute d’un mot plus pratique. Par exemple, si on a une expression reliée à tel ou tel *delta*, on peut dire « Cette bête diminue pour des petites valeurs de *delta*. » On utilise même « sale cabot » pour renforcer le fait qu’elle est moche, et qu’il y a peu d’espoir que l’on puisse montrer que sa valeur absolue s’amoindrit.

Est-ce qu’il y a quelque chose de semblable en français ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Pour "bête", "gars"**

Le français regorge de mots au sens imprécis, équivalents anglais de *thing*, *stuff*, *doohickey*, *thingamajog*.

Tu peux utiliser des mots familiers comme:

- *truc*
- *bidule*
- *machin*
- *machin-chose*
- mais aussi *machin-truc-chose, truc-machin-chose, machin-truc-bidule-chouette, truc-muche-bidule-chose-machin-chouette* ou toute permutation de *truc, machin, muche, bidule, chose, chouette* qui commence par *truc*, *machin* ou *bidule*.

> Le truc tend vers 0.
>
> Le machin est pas défini sur l'intervalle.

Si tu utilises une version plus longue, elle signifie que l'objet mathématique est de plus en plus bizarre, incompréhensible, mal défini, tordu.

Tu peux aussi utiliser ces mots comme adjectifs épithètes.

> Je sais pas si l'ensemble bidule a les propriétés nécessaires pour prouver quoi que ce soit.
>
> La fonction machin a sa limite qui diverge.

Ici "la fonction machin" veut dire "cette fonction dont on parlait".

Ou comme méta variable comme "foo" et "bar" en anglais

> La fonction machin est strictement plus grande que la fonction bidule sur tout l'intervalle.

Pour dire "la fonction *A* est strictement plus grande que la fonction *B* sur tout l'intervalle".

Plus difficile, tu peux aussi utiliser [*schmilblick*](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schmilblick), du nom d'un vieux jeu radio-télévisé:

- schmilblick, dans le sens de truc complexe ou inutile
- faire avancer le schmilblick, faire avancer la compréhension ou la solution du problème

Si tu veux faire rire, n’hésite pas à inventer une étymologie dans ta langue natale pour ce mot, et à la changer souvent.

**Pour sale sabot**

- *merdique*, très familier mais pas forcement vulgaire, qui peut être utilisé pour un objet qui génère des difficultés de calcul, mais aussi un contre-exemple qui marche bien
- *faire merder*, dans le sens de faire dysfonctionner
- *pourri*, dans le sens de qui marche mal, mal fait
- *à la con*, expression très familière pour stupide ou simple, mais aussi trivial. Comme ça peut aussi vouloir dire stupide, le plus simple est dans un premier temps de l'utiliser pour tes propres trouvailles.
- *pourrir*, dans le sens d'affecter négativement
- je pense que tu peux te permettre, toi seul, d'inventer l'expression "aux sabots crottés", par référence a l'expression dans ta langue natale et [Brassens](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JFfHCtw3Nqc), ça fera rire si la personne connaît.

> J'avais besoin d'une fonction merdique pour l'optimiseur, j'ai pris la banane de Rosenbrock.
>
> C'est quoi l'exemple canonique de fonction pourrie dans les fonctions C0 qui font merder Fourier ?
>
> Les conditions aux limites ont pourri le schéma d’intégration, le programme me sort n'importe quoi.
>
> J'ai un contre-exemple à la con, ça marche pas pour l’identité.

Par contre, je n'aurais pas utilisé "se rapetisse", mais plutôt "diminue", même en langage familier, voire "rapetisse" pour une notion géométrique ou un voisinage, mais pas la forme réflexive "se rapetisser".

> Le truc (la sortie, l'ensemble) diminue pour des ptites valeurs de delta.

Comment: désolé, j'arrive pas à mettre les liens dans les mots

Comment: Merci pour avoir approfondi le langage des matheux ! Il y a encore des choses que je veux dire quant à vôtre réponse : Tout d’abord, je voulais écrire *cabot* et pas *sabot*, le « s » n’est qu’une faute de frappe. Néanmoins, toutes les traductions que vous suggérez couvrent le contenu du néerlandais « gedrocht » quand même. Je vous remercie aussi pour m’avoir prévenu quant à « se rapetisser ».

Comment: D’ailleurs, qu’est-ce que veut dire « sortie » ici ? C’est comme un aboutissement, un résultat ?

Comment: Je voulais dire la sortie du programme, le résultat de la fonction, les données en sortie.

Comment: N'oublions pas le nom *merdier*, correspondant a l'adjectif *merdique*.