# “Thing” in French: “chose”, “truc”

Tags: vocabulaire

I have translated "thing" into French. There are two translations there: "chose f" and "truc m".

I am studying the difference between them.

*Chose*:

> - Tout objet concret par opposition aux êtres animés.
> - Désigne une entité abstraite, une action, un événement, un énoncé.

Read more at [Larousse](http://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/chose/15712#TJ5SV6MsfhYb0rch.99).

*Truc*:

> - Moyen adroit, procédé ingénieux pour réussir.
> - Mot par lequel on désigne quelque chose ou, avec une majuscule, quelqu'un dont on ne sait pas ou plus le nom.

Read more at [Larousse](http://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/truc/80048#QycEpyakJxCrdobf.99).

What is the difference?

Answer (score 4):

"chose" et "truc" sont synonymes quand on parle de quelque chose que l'on ne peut/veut pas nommer, à la différence que "chose" est plus formel que "truc".

Aussi "truc" a un autre sens comme vous l'avez noté, dans le sens "trucs et astuces" pour les jeux vidéos, ou dans le contexte de la magie quand on parle du "truc" d'un tour de magie (que le spectateur ne voit pas, et qui induit donc le tour).

Pour plus de synonymes comme "machin" ou "bidule", Stéphane Gimenez a écrit [une réponse ici](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/11843/7321).

Comment: Peut-être aussi l'occasion de mentionner les synonymes du langage encore plus familier : trucmuche, schmilblick, machin-chose ?

Comment: ou encore "bidule"

Comment: @Laure j'ai ajouté un lien :)

Answer (score 3):

Both translates to "thing" but their meaning is quite different.
Most of the time both refers to something you don't have a name for:

> Je dois te dire un truc. / Je dois te dire quelque chose.
>
> Je cherche un truc en bois grand comme ça. Vous ne l'auriez pas vu ?
>
> Les choses qui nous entourent peuvent être matérielles ou immatérielles.

There is many subtleties about their usage:

- Firstly, "truc" is avoided in formal language.
- If you are familiarly speaking about someone you don't remember the name, you can call him "Truc". (but it's not very nice)
- "le truc" can also mean "the trick", like in "the magician's trick".
- "un truc" can be also some clever way to proceed, like a life hack ("truc et astuces").
- "X est la chose de Y", when speaking about persons, means X is completely submissive toward Y.
- If you are speaking about some monster (eg "The Thing from the depths"), you have to use "chose" ("La Chose des profondeurs").